# Groovy: how to merge list of maps to a single map by a property, combining different map values into a inner lists

Tags: groovy

I would like to merge a list of maps (which is actually a result list of a query with jeft join many-to-many relationship tables) to a single map that will contain a single key:value pair if they are equal in all maps and key:[list-of-values] in case values are different for a certain key. For example having a list of maps:

```
[  
[name:john, title:senior, access:floor1],  
[name:john, title:senior, access:floor2]  
]
```

to a map

```
[name:john, title:senior, access:[floor1, floor2]]
```

Comment: In left to right order of precidence (so name is effectively a primary key)?  ie: what happens to `[name:'carol', title:'senior', access:'floor1']`?

Comment: @tim_yates 
Never happens. Everything is already grouped by an actual primary key. All entries are equal except of an 'access'

Comment: Ahhh, so it's just `access` you need to group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given an input list of maps:

```
def input = [  
    [name:'john', title:'senior', access:'floor1'],  
    [name:'john', title:'senior', access:'floor2'],  
    [name:'carol', title:'senior', access:'floor2']
]
```

We can group by the first two (again, as a map):

```
input.groupBy { [name: it.name, title: it.title] }
```

Which gives us:

```
[
    [name:john, title:senior]:[
        [name:john, title:senior, access:floor1],
        [name:john, title:senior, access:floor2]
    ],
    [name:carol, title:senior]:[
        [name:carol, title:senior, access:floor2]
    ]
]
```

And then we can collect them up in the required output form, giving us:

```
input.groupBy { [name: it.name, title: it.title] }.collect { k, v ->
    k + [access: v.access]
}
```

Which gives the result:

```
[
    [name:john, title:senior, access:[floor1, floor2]],
    [name:carol, title:senior, access:[floor2]]
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what i am looking for (except records are already grouped by name, but nevertheless). Let me check...

Comment: Thank you so much, Tim! Just what i needed!

Comment: No worries, have fun! 